# Improving BOSH Throughput

Tags: ajax, xmpp

I've implemented a web chat system using Jabber, with the Tigase server and an Ajax-based client communicating over BOSH using JsJac, with Apache mod_proxy forwarding the HTTP traffic to Tigase. This works reasonably well, but I've noticed one major gap in performance versus a desktop Jabber client (like Exodus), particularly when joining a multi-user chat with a long history of messages.

Specifically, from monitoring HTTP traffic, it appears that the server can only send one XMPP message per HTTP request-response cycle. For normal usage this is fine (we're getting roughly 80-100msec round-trip times, which isn't too bad), but when loading MUC history it can be  a real drag.

So my question is: does Jabber or BOSH provide any mechanism for bundling or streaming messages that might apply to this use case? Are any clients and servers out there implementing something like this already? Or would I have to modify Tigase and JsJac myself (which is certainly possible, but not ideal)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Sounds like an awesome project...

Comment: Not exactly, but it's a topic I'm still interested in. I'll check out Alec's answer below and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the BOSH server can collect as many responses from the Jabber server and send them as one single response to the client. I am the author of one such BOSH library: http://code.google.com/p/node-xmpp-bosh/.

The response body has nothing to do with the request body in case of BOSH. I mean that the response could and mostly will be a response to an unrelated request (mostly a later request).

Comment: This was apparently a Tigase problem (though I no longer have a Tigase instance available, so I can't verify it). I have not gotten this problem in other configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a BOSH communications solution with Java on the server and GWT on the client (a browser). A C client implementation has also been made. Presently, I am in the process of making the solution available online for tests. Please take a look at the following Google presentation to see if my solution is relevant for your business:

https://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AUPL-u98h45WZGQzNWNjOGhfMGd6bWI1NmNk&hl=en&authkey=CPTzrWc

To see the speaker notes, make sure you hit the "View Speaker Notes" button in the bottom-right corner of the page.